# trying to create a login and signup php system

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a login and sign up system with PHP
the signup system work but checking for an existing value in the db wont work to create the login.

here is my db

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|Member_ID | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | None    | auto_increment |
|FirstName |char(20)     | NO   |     | None    |                |
|LastName  |char(20)     | NO   |     | None    |                |
|Email     |varchar(50)  | NO   |     | None    |                |
|User_Password |char(20) | NO   |     | None    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The following code is my sign up and it works

```
<?php
require_once 'Database_conx.php';


$get_first_name = $_POST["Firstnamebox"];
$get_last_name  = $_POST["Lastnamebox" ];
$get_password   = md5($_POST["passwordbox" ]);
$get_email      = $_POST["emailaddbox" ];

$firstname = trim($get_first_name);
$lastname  = trim($get_last_name);
$passcode  = trim($get_password);
$email     = trim($get_email);

$processvalue = "Insert INTO Registration ( FirstName, LastName, User_Password,Email )
              VALUES ('$firstname' ,'$lastname', '$passcode' ,'$email'   )";


if (mysqli_query($conn, $processvalue)) {

echo 'Sucess in submiting data in db ';

} else {
   echo "error in testing :" .mysqli_error($conn);
}  

mysqli_close($conn)

 ?>
```

the following code is to check to see if a value exist in the db

```
 <?php
    require_once 'Database_conx.php';

     if(isset($_POST['loginbtn'])){
       $db =  mysqli_select_db($conn, 'Star5_db');


    $email = $_POST["loginemailbox"];
    $password = $_POST["loginpasswordbox"];

    $e = trim($email);
    $p = trim($password);

    $pc = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Email = $e AND User_Password = $p");


  if (empty($e)){ 
      echo " oops you're missing your email";

  }

     if(empty($p)){
        echo "<br>Please type in your password </br>";
     } 

  if($pc)
  {
      echo " <br> $e. is found in the database :)</br>";
  } 
  elseif (empty ($e)) {
    echo '   ';

} 
elseif (!filter_var($e,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === TRUE) {
    echo ("<br>$e is not a valid email<br>");
}

else
  {
      echo " <br> $e. not found in db </br>" .  mysqli_error();
  }  

  mysqli_close($pc); 

}

      }
  ?>
```

can any one tell me what am i doing wrong

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a (poorly) *hashed* password in the database, but then you are searching for an unhashed, *plain text* match when the user tries to log in.

You need to hash the password the user submits and compare the result to whatever is in the database.

Comment: can you please provide me with some code
isn't md5 good for hashing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($pc==1) {
  echo " <br> $e. is found in the database :)</br>";
}
```

Comment: it returns   not found in db